# How Leibniz invented the Binary System?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, binary

Do you know which reasoning and observations made Leibniz invent the Binary system ? Some say that he was inspired by Chinese mathematicians do we have any record of how he came with this idea ?

Comment: You can see [here](http://www.leibniz-translations.com/binary.htm) for the translation of Leibniz's text.

Comment: The "source" seems to be (also) the speculations on the meaning of the [trigrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua) contained into the the ancient Chinese classic [I Ching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Ching) and his purported originator [Fu Xi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuxi).

Comment: You can see also [here](http://www.eipiphiny.org/books/history-of-binary.pdf).

Comment: thank you for the link ! as a french speaker I had the pleasure to read his original publication but he does not state precisely ow he came up with the idea although Fu Xi is quoted...

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the invention of the method of calculus. The slope y/x us making x to be the thickness of 1. Then del x was used as 0. Also in number theory, what are the numbers that has meaning beyond just to "count". Then 0 and 1 are the only numbers. Also the truth of Yin and Yang really are every where by as big as the heliocentric world and the center of the universe which the Sun revolves around ,to as small as an atom, which Z numbers of electrons encircles the nucleus. Also action and reaction, the action is Yang and has inertia but reaction would not even exist without first having action. If you are motivated , you should go along this path and decipher the secret of prime numbers. Fuxi used the binary to have numbered the first 8 digits and the code in his map was first deciphered by some French guy. And Lebniz used the Eight digits to match with the Christian holy number 7. Although, fuxi has used the eighth digits,that is 7, to have described heaven, seemingly..but I have not seen anything special with the first 8 digits and I am not motivated to find out about what's special just like I don't with deciphering the secret in prime numbers.But maybe you can, and you may have it published so I will know in the future. :)

Comment: Wow, this almost looks like bot-generated spam. It's just barely coherent enough that I believe it was actually written by a person, otherwise I'd flag it.